# How do I execute a batch file in administrator mode

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to write a batch file to share a folder across my network using `net share` but it needs administrator privileges. I dont know how to execute this command in admin mode.

When you right click cmd.exe in Windows search and select "Run as administrator" it doesn't ask me the password, but when I write a batch code using `runas` command, it ask for a password. Why is it so?

I used following commands

```
runas.exe /profile /user:administrator "cmd.exe"

start /wait cmd.exe /k "net share Inputs=Folder_Path /GRANT:Everyone,FULL"
```

and didnt work.

I am using Win 7 32-bit

Also, somewhere I saw that the following will also to be executed after the folder is shared

```
Icacls Folder_Path /grant Everyone:F /inheritance:e /T
```

Is this required?

Please help

Comment: How are you invoking this batch file?

Comment: One option is to create a shortcut to the batch file, then set the properties on the shortcut to require elevation (and always use the shortcut to run the file).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I am planning to call it through a C# code. I know its possible through c# itself, but to me, it looked little complicated to me...

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Thanks. I tried using a shortcut but when I opened it through batch file, it didnt open the cmd.exe in admin mode. Actually, I cant set the 'Run as administrator' in batch file shortcut (disabled here). Can you please let me know the way forward in this method?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do it the way suggested in the answer you accepted. Not if you are invoking the script from C#. There's a much simpler way.

Comment: Oh really!. Thanks. Please let us all know about it.

Comment: I need these commands in C# code to automate sharing and unsharing a folder based on the scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your batch script to ask for elevation if needed, [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/home/BatchGotAdmin) might help you.  I adapted it to use in a batch script I serve from the web like this:

```
REM  --> Check for permissions
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system">nul 2>NUL

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" (
        del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        echo Failed to acquire elevated privilege.  Try saving this script and running it from your Desktop.
        echo;
        echo Press any key to exit.
        pause>NUL
        goto :EOF
    )
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "%*", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    cscript /nologo "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    goto :EOF

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
:--------------------------------------

:: The rest of the script goes here...
```

Regarding the "Try saving this script" message, if the user attempts to open the batch script directly from the web browser, browser security might block the elevation.  I had to include that to remind my users to save the script first, then run it independently outside the web browser.

Anyway, salt to taste.

Comment: Pretty cool, @Rojo.  This is one I will remember.